# Batch file net user command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that will set a user's account, Windows-7, password expiry date to 60 days from the current date.

I know about this command -> `net user [username] /expires:06/30/11` but I do not want to update the batch file with the correct date every time I run it....I want to run the batch, and have it set to expire 60 days from the date I execute the batch file automatically.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get the date in 60 days

```
@echo off
:: date yesterday -1 or any number
set day=60
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "data=%mm%/%dd%/%yyyy%"

echo %data%
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

That expires the account. It does not expire the password or force a password change after X days.